# Print email addresses to a file in Perl

Tags: perl

I have been scouring this site and others to find the best way to do what I need to do but to no avail. Basically I have a text file with some names and email addresses. Each name and email address is on its own line. I need to get the email addresses and print them to another text file. So far all I have been able to print is the "no email addresses found" message. Any thoughts? Thanks!!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

open(IN, "<contacts.txt") || die("file not found");
#chooses the file to read
open(OUT, ">emailaddresses.txt");
#prints file
$none = "No emails found!";
$line = <IN>;

for ($line)
{
    if ($line =~ /[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}/g)
    {
        print (OUT $line);
    }
    else
    {
        print (OUT $none);
    }
}

close(IN);
close(OUT);
```

Comment: Can we see some sample input?

Comment: The regular expression you're using assumes the email addresses use nothing but capital letters. Is that correct? Also, trying to match email addresses with a regular expression is nearly an exercise in futility. See [Mail::RFC822::Address](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) for more.

Comment: You're only iterating through one line of your file...

Answer (score 8):

First, **always** `use strict; use warnings`. This helps writing correct scripts, and is an invaluable aid when debugging.

Also, use a three-arg-open:

```
open my $fh, "<", $filename or die qq(Can't open "$filename": $!);
```

I included the *reason* for failure (`$!`), which is a good practice too.

The idiom to read files (on an open filehandle) is:

```
while (<$fh>) {
  chomp;
  # The line is in $_;
}
```

or

```
while (defined(my $line = <$fh>)) { chomp $line; ... }
```

What you did was to read one line into `$line`, and loop over that *one* item in the `for` loop.

(Perl has a notion of *context*. Operators like `<$fh>` behave differently depending on context. Generally, using a scalar variable (`$` sigil) forces scalar context, and `@`, the sigil for arrays, causes list context. This is quite unlike PHP.)

I'd rewrite your code like:

```
use strict; use warnings;
use feature 'say';
my $regex = qr/[A-Z0-9._%+-]+\@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}/i; # emails are case insensitive
my $found = 0;

while (<>) { # use special ARGV filehandle, which usually is STDIN
  while (/($regex)/g) {
    $found++;
    say $1;
  }
}
die "No emails found\n" unless $found;
```

Invoked like `perl script.pl <contacts.txt >emailaddresses.txt`. The shell is your friend, and creating programs that can be piped from and to is good design.

#### Update

If you *want* to hardcode the filenames, we would combine the above script with the three-arg open I have shown:

```
use strict; use warnings; use feature 'say';
use autodie; # does `... or die "Can't open $file: $!"` for me
my $regex = qr/[A-Z0-9._%+-]+\@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}/i;
my $found = 0;

my $contact_file = "contacts.txt";
my $email_file   = "emailaddresses.txt";

open my $contact, "<", $contact_file;
open my $email, ">", $email_file;

while (<$contact>) {    # read from the $contact filehandle
  while (/($regex)/g) { # the /g is optional if there is max one address per line
    $found++;
    say {$email} $1;    # print to the $email file handle. {curlies} are optional.
  }
}
die "No emails found\n" unless $found; # error message goes to STDERR, not to the file
```

Comment: +1: really nice "general tips", and kudos on mentioning the `<>` variant.

Comment: Thank you amon, excellent explanations. My only issue with your revision is that my requirements state that the emails need to be written to a separate text file. Does your rewrite allow for that? Also, what does the say $1 do?
A sample of what the text file I am reading from would be something like this:
Jane Doe
jdoe@address.com
123456
John Doe
john.doe@testing.ca
654321
etc etc

Comment: @motherconfessor You previously didn't mention how the contents of the file were structured. My approach will extract the email addresses (without the rest of the line) and print them out. The `$1` refers to the contents of a *capture*. You can use captures to extract the matched text from regexes. You specify on the command line where the output goes, by appending `>target`. The `>` is a redirection operator on most shells. Using shell redirections is more flexible than hardcoding filenames in your script.

Comment: Sorry, the text file example didn't display properly in my last comment. Jane Doe (new line) jdoe@address.com (new line) 123456 (new line) John Doe (new line) etc etc etc. Each piece of info is on it's own line. Would this make a difference? Also I understand that using shell is much more flexible than hard coding, however, for the purpose of the exercise, how would I hard code it in?

Comment: @motherconfessor I posted an update combining my loop with the three-arg-open I talked about.

Comment: @amon that is awesome, thank you so much. I think it makes sense to me now.